# pickled figures look bigger than original

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle, spyder

I save the figures I generate using pickle. Here is an example cope I run on spyder:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
plt.suptitle('RANDOM')
ax[0].plot(np.random.rand(100), color='r', linewidth=2)
ax[0].set_title('Random 0')
ax[1].plot(np.random.rand(100), color='r', linewidth=2)
ax[1].set_title('Random 1')
plt.tight_layout()

# Save figure
pickle.dump(fig, open('random_fig.pickle', 'wb'))
```

However, when I load the figure back, it looks way bigger than the one I saved and it is as big as my computer screen. I load the figure using the following code:

```
figx = pickle.load(open('random_fig.pickle', 'rb'))
figx.show()
```

Attached I leave a screenshot of the figure I generate with the code ('original') and the one I load afterwards ('bigger').

Do you know why is that?

[image: Original Figure]
[image: Bigger Figure]

Comment: Question: Why do you need to pickle your figures? It seems like an odd format to save them. Why not use SVG instead?

Comment: I would like to keep them interactive. Once I save them as png/svg/pdf they are not interactive anymore when I open them back.